# Can't use Predefined variables under environment tags in YAML azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Below is my YAML code, where I'm trying to use the yaml predefined variable $(Build.BuildNumber) under the tags section for environments, but it doesn't work at all. It looks more like a limitation in the Environments' tags block which I think needs the value to be present during compile time.

```
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Test Deploy'
  jobs:
  - deployment: Test_job
    environment:
      name: myEnvironment
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: $(Build.BuildNumber) 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
            steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: Deploy-Steps...
```

The error I get is:

**##[error]No resource were found in the environment with ID 17 matching the specified criteria: ResourceId , ResourceName , ResourceType VirtualMachine, Tags $(Build.BuildNumber).**

Comment: Some variables are available, some aren't. But the runtime syntax is probably not helping. Have you tried: `${{ vars['Build.BuildNumber'] }}`?

Comment: this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use the syntax `${{}}` for compile time in the tag of the environment.

Example:

`tags: ${{variables['Build.DefinitionName']}}`

```
tags: ${{variables['Build.SourceVersion']}}
```

However, we cannot use `$(Build.BuildId)`, `$(Build.BuildURL)`, and `$(Build.BuildNumber)`, because their values aren't set at the time expressions are evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already. It works with Build.DefinitionName, but I need to use Build.BuildNumber or some other property which is unique for every build run, is there any other variable as such?

Comment: Hi @owesom, what about `tags: ${{variables['Build.SourceVersion']}}`, it would be unique when you make change to your code.

Comment: This works, thank you!! wondering if there is any alternative workaround for Build.BuildNumber..

Comment: or maybe something which is very unique for a build run...?

Comment: Hi @owesom, I checked the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), but it seems that most of the unique build values cannot be used here.