# How to run deployment job using only agent pool agents instead of environment agents

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
- deployment: Job_Start_Installation
    displayName: Start Installation
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    environment:
      name: MyEnvironment
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: Active
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:          
          - template: '../Steps/StartInstallation.yml'
```

This is my YAML code for one of my deployment jobs. I am currently using Environments to execute the steps on multiple machines within the environment. This works very well.

Now, I want to achieve the same result using regular Agent pool agents, without relying on Environments or deployment jobs anymore. What is the best way for doing this. I found that there something exists like each loops, strategy with parallel properties, etc... Need to know what is the recommended and best way for doing this.

Comment: A deployment job is a collection of steps that are run sequentially against the environment. Would you please let me know why you don't want to use Environment or deployment job? What exactly is your pipeline going to do? Deploy to your VMs or something else?

Comment: My jobs will reboot the VMs and start the product installation and during product installation we have a custom step that again registers the agents back to the same pool.  Azure DevOps has a limitation regarding the use of $(Build.BuildNumber) in the tags section under environments based deployment jobs. bcoz these values are not accessible during compile time. but there is no such limitation with Agent based jobs. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538892/cant-use-predefined-variables-under-environment-tags-in-yaml-azure-devops-pipel/77540736?noredirect=1#comment136723112_77540736

Comment: Hi @owesom, hope you are well! Would you please let me know whether you have checked my answer below? Feel free to let me know if you have any question. If it's helpful for you, to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way the agent job can do exactly the same thing as the deployment job. But you can use [job.strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job-strategy?view=azure-pipelines) and [pool.demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool-demands?view=azure-pipelines) as  a workaround.

When using self-hosted agents, you can [add new user-defined capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#configure-agent-capabilities) and use `pool.demands` to filter the agents with the target capabilities. For your case, you can add `Build.BuildNumber` as user-defined capability. For the sake of illustration, I have added a capability named "tag" with the value "test" to my self-hosted agent.
[image]

**1. Using strategy: parallel**

```
jobs:
- job: Test
  strategy:
    parallel: 4
  pool: 
    name: Default
    demands: tag -equals "test"
  steps:
```

Using this strategy, the same job will be executed multiple times, depending on the value of `parallel`. But you need to make sure you have purchased enough [parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted), otherwise the same job may be run multiple times on the same agent.

**2. Using strategy: matrix, maxParallel**

```
jobs:
- job: Test
  strategy:
    matrix:
      VM1:
        agentName: VZIYAN620VM
      VM2:
        agentName: VTIANM336VM

  pool: 
    name: Default
    demands: 
    - Agent.Name -equals $(agentName)
    - tag -equals test
```

Using this strategy, the job will try to run on each agent. It will run successfully on agents that meet the demand and fail on others. But you need to define all your agents' name in the matrix.
[image]